# Transaction in VS2008 and SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, transactions

If I'm already using transactions in my stored procedure, is it feasible to use transactions in VS 2008 to call the procedure multiple times?

What I am trying to do is re-use my insert single record stored procedure which already uaes transactions. I want to insert multiple records using this insert single record stored procedure, and rollback if exceptions happen.

I have a feeling that this is not best practice, and I suspect it may cause problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but most of the time would be round-trips to the database server.

Suggestions:

- load temp table, call stored proc on same connection
- [use XML/Table parameter on stored proc](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- Batch the stored proc calls (which means submitting a big string)

Comment: I was thinking that using a transaction inside a transaction seem to be a bit weird..
But i think using the 2nd suggestion of yours is preferred. Since i will be inserting multiple record into multiple table..

So i marked yours as answer.. :)